# Unable to fetch deleted contacts from ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI

Tags: android, kotlin, contacts, android-contacts

I am trying to fetch deleted contacts from Android contacts table. After searching some Stack Overflow links, best way to fetch the deleted contacts is by using `ContactsContract.DeletedContacts`. I am able to fetch the deleted contacts from DeletedContacts table.

```
val deletedContactsProjection = arrayOf(ContactsContract.DeletedContacts.CONTACT_ID,ContactsContract.DeletedContacts.CONTACT_DELETED_TIMESTAMP)
val contactLastDeletedTimeStamp = SharedPreferenceManager.instance.getLongFromPreference("contact_sync_last_updated_timestamp")
val deletedContactSelection = ContactsContract.DeletedContacts.CONTACT_DELETED_TIMESTAMP + " > ?";
val deletedContactSelectionArgs = arrayOf<String>(contactLastDeletedTimeStamp.toString())
var deletedContactsCursor = context.contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.DeletedContacts.CONTENT_URI, deletedContactsProjection,deletedContactSelection, deletedContactSelectionArgs,null)
```

Using the above cursor I'm able to fetch the last deleted contact. When I checked the ContactsContract.DeletedContacts.CONTACT_ID of the deleted contact from cursor, it's same as the contact id which I deleted. But the problem is when I'm trying to fetch the contact  from ContactsContract.Contacts table using the ContactsContract.DeletedContacts.CONTACT_ID its always returning null.

This is the query I'm using:

```
String[] contactNumberProjection = {ContactsContract.Contacts._ID};
String contactId = deletedContactsCursor.getString(deletedContactsCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.DeletedContacts.CONTACT_ID));
String contactSelection = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + " = ?";
String[] contactSelectionArg = {contactId};
Cursor contactCursor =
context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,contactNumberProjection,contactSelection,contactSelectionArg,null);
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a contact is **deleted** from the main `Contacts` table it is obviously **removed** from that table so that the contact will not appear in the Contacts apps the user is using the view their present contacts.

So you can only get details of deleted contacts in the `DeletedContacts` table.

Comment: then how to get the details like mobile number and username for the deleted contact should i change the query?? Because the deletedcontacts table does not contain any details except contact id and contact deleted time.

Comment: you can't... it's more useful for apps that sync contacts, this will let them know that contact X was recently deleted and they should sync that deletion.

Comment: ya i too need to sync my contacts but im not usng sync adapter to sync contacts.Because of this i may need to loop contacts and check which contact has been deleted.If i am able to get contact mobile number then i can just query that number and delete it from my app database.

Comment: then store the contact-ids in your local database, and use that to figure out the contact that was recently deleted. NEVER use phone numbers or emails as keys to a unique contact! Multiple contact may share the same phone and/or email, you might be deleting the wrong contact